# What are the disadvantages of using Kerberos authentication for secure micro-service to micro-service communication?

Tags: kerberos, microservices

Sam Newman's "Building Microservices" book has described several methods that can be used to perform secure service to service communication. Such as

1. HTTPS Basic Authentication
2. Client Certificates
3. HMAC API Keys

I think Kerberos protocol can also be used for service to service authentication. But I found less references of using Kerberos protocol. Are there any disadvantages of using kerberos protocol in microservice architecture than other methods?

Comment: Kerberos auth relies on a separate KDC service on a separate infrastructure, which means extra latency. Allocate 2+ dedicated bare-metal hosts if you want something reliable, install Kerberos MIT (or similar), setup the sync between servers, etc. -- or plug into an existing Corporate LDAP with Kerberos support.

Comment: Note that Kerberos requires **canonical DNS host names** to protect against IP spoofing and the like; plus **synchronized clocks** to protect against replay attacks; etc. That's a lot of constraints for the average toy-microservice-on-unstable-Docker-platform.

Comment: Also, Kerberos does not provide any auth cache out-of-the-box. You have to implement it yourself -- or steal it from existing OpenSource stacks: Hadoop uses either a "delegation token" (shared between nodes - Kerberos was never designed for distributed computing!) or a signed cookie (for UIs and REST APIs).

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter - What would you recommend as an alternative to kerberos for microservices environments. I.e. to protect from eavesdropping of popular bearers token. Would be thankful for some hints.